# clReleaseCommandQueue hangs when queue contains unexecuted kernels that are waiting on completion events

Tags: opencl

Releasing a command queue should, in my opinion, remove all unexecuted kernels, even if they are waiting on completion events.

I am using an AMD card, and it seems that I have to manually set completion events to COMPLETE in order to successfully release the command queue.

Is this a bug in the AMD implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If in doubt, always refer to the specification:

> **clReleaseCommandQueue** performs an implicit flush to issue any previously queued OpenCL 
>   commands in *command_queue*.

So, this is in fact expected behaviour.

Comment: Thanks. So you are saying that if there are queued commands waiting for other events, that the queue cannot be released? This makes releasing resources at program end a bit complicated.

Comment: That is the case. If these commands are waiting on user events, you can call `clSetUserEvent()` with a negative value for the execution status to cause all commands waiting on the event to terminate without executing.

Comment: Cool. Thanks. Did not know this. (I think you meant `clSetUserEventStatus()`)